# Getting sync(uploading) multipale data on the remote server from iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am try to sync or upload the data on the remote server from iPhone but not getting it. I try this from 1 week but didn't succeed.
How can solve this. I am using the *NSURLConnection* methods or any one give idea on 
**ASIHTTPRequest method** but I am new for *ASIHTTPRequest*. I need this method only for this code:

```
- (void)sendRequestforContent
{   
    //this for finding the date of sync on the server
    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    //Create the dateformatter object
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    //Set the required date format
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    //Get the string date
    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSError *error = nil; 

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil; 
    NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; 

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

    NSString *boundary = @"-------------------a9d8vyb89089dy70"; 

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary]; 

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 

    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    //this is for TOKEN_API
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"Token\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[tokenapi dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    //this for the CONTENT_ID
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"contentID\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[content_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //this for the CONTENTTYPE_ID
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"contentTypeID\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    NSString *ContentTypeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",content_type];
    [postBody appendData:[ContentTypeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //this for the CONTENT_Location_Id
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"contentLocationID\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[contenLocation_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //this is for the User_Caption
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"userCaption\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[user_caption dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //this is for the User_Comment
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"userComment\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[user_comment dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    //this for the Tags
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"tags\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[tag dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //this for the Date_Record
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"dateRecorded\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[date_recorded dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //this for the image_data
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"image_file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",@"image.jpg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:image];

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



    //this for the Share_type
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"shareType\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    NSString *ShareString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",share_type];
    [postBody appendData:[ShareString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //this for the Views
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"views\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
     NSString *ViewsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",views];
    [postBody appendData:[ViewsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //this for the PLAY_time
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"playTime\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    NSString *TimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",play_time];
    [postBody appendData:[TimeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //this for the Posted_By
    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"postedBy\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    [postBody appendData:[postred_by dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 


    //this for the AVG_Rating
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"avgRating\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    NSString *AvgString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",avg_rating];
    [postBody appendData:[AvgString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [postBody appendData:[@"Content-disposition: form-data; name=\"LastSyncDate\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    [postBody appendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [request setHTTPBody:postBody];

    NSData *shoutData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:shoutData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}
```

It is not going into the this methods

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{      
    loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", loginStatus);  
}
```

It show me HTML page on console.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code?

Comment: @AugustLilleaas is that i am doing wrong

Comment: @AugustLilleaas   check it out my updata question above

Comment: You don't show what the errors are that you're getting.  What EXACTLY is not working?  You probably want to print out the response and error return values to see what's going on.

Comment: @Flyingdiver look at above updated question and code with error

Comment: If you are getting a error message as a response from web that means either something is wrong with the web or you are not sending your data in a format it can understand.

Comment: The response from the web server specifically says there's an error there.  Also, you won't get a call to connectionDidFinishLoading:, that's only for asynchronous connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://192.168.0.1:96/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=Content&Command=New"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

NSMutableData *postBody;//Here comes your data that you have created in the question
NSString *msgLength = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", [postBody length]];//use either [postBody length] or [postBody bytes], I am not sure about it

ASIFormDataRequest *serverRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[serverRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"];
[serverRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:msgLength];
[serverRequest appendPostData:postBody];
[serverRequest setDelegate:self];
[serverRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(sendAlertsRequestDone:)];
[serverRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(sendAlertsRequestWentWrong:)];
[serverRequest setUploadProgressDelegate:progressView];// here progressView is UIProgressbar
[serverRequest startAsynchronous];

[urlString release];
[url release];
[postBody release];
[msgLength release];
```